# Conditional expectation - sigma algebra generated by not disjoint sets

Tags: probability-theory

I 'd like to ask about condinational expectation computation when
$\mathbb{E}(X | {\mathcal G})$ when ${\mathcal G}$ is generated by sigma-algebra on two sets - not disjoint. Lets consider simple discrete example when $\Omega=\{ a,b,c,d,e \}$ and $A = \{ a,b\}$ and $B=\{ b,c,d\}$

There is a formula for computation which works when sigma algebra is generated by disjoint sets or  by partition
$$E[X| {\mathcal G}]= \sum_{p \in P} 1_p E[X|p]$$
My question is how to calculate condinational expectation on sigma algebra when it is not generated by disjoint sets. Which formula works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, $\mathcal G$ is generated by the partition
$$\big\{ \{a\}, \{b\}, \{c,d\} \big \}.$$
In general, any finite sigma-algebra is generated by some partition.

Comment: ok so then sigma algebra is generated. To calculate -  same formula is used in regards to probabilities $P(A),P(B),P(C \cup D), P(A'),..$ ?

Comment: @vearis Yeah, just use the formula you already know for partitions.

Comment: thank you very much